# Upload to board with no USB connection

Tags: avr, atmega32u4, programmer

I have a Spark Fun Pro Micro (ATmega32U4) without a USB connection (it was broken off at an earlier point) that I want to use to duplicate a prototype running on another Pro Micro.

How can I upload a sketch to an Arduino without a USB connection?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to solder back the connector or to buy a new board.

Ways to use a board with ATmega32u4 without USB for development are:

- ICSP programming
- upload over a serial bootloader.

Both require additional hardware.

For ICSP upload you need a programmer device. After configuring it, select the programmer in Tools menu and you can use "Upload using programmer" from the sketch menu. It is even possible to create a custom board definition which will use "Upload using programmer" with the "Upload" button from the toolbar.

To make serial upload possible you will need and USB-to-TTL-Serial adapter and  Optiboot compiled for the 32u4. To burn the bootloader you will need an ICSP programmer or a second Arduino to use with the [Arduino as ISP sketch](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP).

Answer (score -1):

Use a [programmer](https:////https://www.ebay.com/itm/234476270925?hash=item3697dff54d:g:JnwAAOSwnk9iOKEh&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsHjuKzkVJX5dTKd7OsCy1E%2BXU0DUH8PTbbLcgwpYpg7ogH4xfkh2SislVKc9c3Ca82xT24r4%2B0ePnzPYlUb8%2FdL14nr3hMP6tFWlFDynpay76gLsKo%2B%2FF7A9gt9psDvOevdlsoS%2F2U%2BTVYwgPwmQILUQxYZvz4IUdbxkaEWBUFpVyYErcj8Sn5ZTn5zDmHa%2FawsbvOD13sw4E%2F9dcmn3npK3D2szluez84DYmx9uOmVj%7Ctkp%3ABlBMULyf3Z7oYA), such as one based on CH341A that has pins broken out for CLK, CS, MOSI, MIOS [sic], GND, 3.3V, and connected those to pins on the Pro Micro as follows:

```
Programmer    Pro Micro
CLK-----------15 (SCK)
CS------------RST
MOSI----------16 (MOSI)
MIOS----------14 (MISO)
GND-----------GND
3.3V----------RAW
```

It doesn't appear that the programmer is supported in the Arduino IDE, so I grabbed [chavrprog](https://github.com/Trel725/chavrprog).

And ran the command `$ sudo ./chavrprog -d mega32u4 -a s ~/Arduino/test/test.ino.leonardo.hex`

Comment: I see. The upload program implements the protocol. This is a very nonstandard solution for the problem in the question.